# batch file to return next to last line of text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, dos

I have a file that contains the output of a file compare thats written to a text file:
`Comparing files C:\LOGS\old.txt and C:\LOGS\NEW.TXT

***** C:\LOGS\old.txt

***** C:\LOGS\NEW.TXT

folder_thats_different

*****`
I need to pull out the next to last line "folder_thats_different" and put in a new string:
`folder contains a file that is different: folder_thats_different`

Yes, I know I can use another language, but I'm stuck with batch files for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to read it with a for-loop and take the current line, and always save the previous line

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%x in (myFile.txt) do (
    set "previous=!last!"
    set "last=%%x"
)
echo !previous!
```

Comment: for some reason the last line is not working. I get `ECHO is off` instead of it printing the line.

Comment: Then !previous! is empty or miss typed, or the wrong file is taken, replace myFile.txt and you can add an echo in the for-loop to debug the code

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example you can use as a starting point.  Just change the filename in the `set command=` line to the appropriate name (or replace the command with whatever will gerneate the log listing).

```
@echo off
@setlocal

(set command=type test.txt)

for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`%command%`) do call :process_line %%i
echo next to last line: %old_line%
goto :eof

:process_line
(set old_line=%new_line%)
(set new_line=%*)
goto :eof
```

Of course, you'll probably want to do something other than simply echoing the found line.

Comment: Thanks this looks good. How can I use that line and put it into string variable to use later?

Comment: `old_line` is just an environment variable - you can use it like any other.  `set my_string_var=%old_line%`, for example.

Comment: It works, but call's are extremly time intensive. 20times slower than the DelayedExpansion variant.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer works for me. I also added 2 lines after the end to allow it to repeat so I could watch an active log file without having to close and reopen it. I do a lot of debugging for the mods that are used in the game Space Engineers.
My version looks like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%x in (SpaceEngineers.log) do (
    set "previous=!last!"
    set "last=%%x"
)
echo !previous!
timeout 15 /nobreak
se_log
```

The line below stops the batch file from looping too fast and stop the key bypass. To change the amount of time in seconds just change the number "15" to anything you want. To stop the batch file just press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

```
timeout 15 /nobreak
```

The line below is the name of the batch file I made so it will tell CMD to run this again.

```
se_log
```